# iOS auto renewable subscription for unlocking premium content

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, auto-renewing

I am working on an app which is basically a tv/sports/cinema schedule listing app. can I unlock some premium feature in my app with auto renewable subcription and keep a limited version of my app available for unsubscribed users?

P.S : I know the limitations for getting the auto renewable subscription approved for  non newsstand esque apps, but I hear recently they are less strict about it.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"can I unlock some premium feature in my app with auto renewable subcription and keep a limited version of my app available for unsubscribed users? "

Yes, as long as your app falls into certain categories.

Per 11.15 of the App Store Review Guidelines (28-Feb-2015):

> Apps may only use auto-renewing subscriptions for periodicals (newspapers, magazines), business Apps (enterprise, productivity, professional creative, cloud storage), and media Apps (video, audio, voice), or the App will be rejected

You will also be responsible for checking receipts and disabling functionality if the premium subscription is expired.

Comment: Thanks Brad, just wanted to know if its possible as auto renewal seemed much better option to have compared to non renewable subscriptions. Cheers !